# Is it possible to disable the zoom/pan window on a plotly.py candlestick chart?

Tags: python, plotly

I am creating a candlestick plot using plotly.py. I would like to have a horizontal split and place the candlestick data in the top split and some data curves in the bottom bottom split. I do not need panning and zooming and that lower section of the candlestick chart with the zoom/pan controls is getting in my way.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To disable zoom and panning you need to set:
`layout.xaxis.fixedrange = true` and `layout.yaxis.fixedrange = true`.

To hide the controls you need to set `displayModeBar = false`.

In Python this would for example look like this:

```
dcc.Graph(
    id='my-id',
    config={'displayModeBar': False},
   'layout': go.Layout(
       xaxis={'title': 'x-axis','fixedrange':True},
       yaxis={'title': 'y-axis','fixedrange':True})
)
```

Comment: This hides the controls at the top, not what is being asked.

Comment: this is useful for heatmaps

Answer (score 3):

I disabled it with `layout.xaxis.rangeslider.visible = false`

Comment: I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Well done! This is really useful specially if you want to save as image

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to disable individual buttons from the bar.

See the Plotly Python documentation on the `configuration` object: https://plotly.com/python/configuration-options/#removing-modebar-buttons

**example code:**
`fig.show(config={ 'modeBarButtonsToRemove': ['zoom', 'pan'] })`

Answer (score 0):

If you save the file using the control save method, I think that it disables the zoom/pan function. Around October, I had a similar issue, and when I simply saved the chart, the zoom/pan function went away. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks. But that kind of defies the functionality of the chart as it becomes an image and is not interactive anymore.