# Remove select-zoom in and axis pan plotly dash

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to remove the option to zoom in using select in my plotly plot:

[image]

I also want to remove the option to change the y and x axis scales by dragging along the axes:

[image]

How can I acheive this?

Comment: what did you find in documentation and in Google?

Comment: [Is it possible to disable the zoom/pan window on a plotly.py candlestick chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082138/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-zoom-pan-window-on-a-plotly-py-candlestick-chart)

Comment: Plotly doc: [Disable Zoom Events in JavaScript](https://plotly.com/javascript/disable-zoom/)